# Handle PUT requests with Symfony 4 Form

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I used to use edit and update methods in my controller to submit and handle a PUT form submission. It works fine and the code looks like this,

```
public function edit(Category $category): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('category_update', [
            'id' => $category->getId(),
        ]),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ]);

    return $this->render('category/edit.html.twig', [
        'category_form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

public function update(Category $category, Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category, ['method' => 'PUT']);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->flush();

        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }

    return new Response('', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

As PUT is not supported by HTML forms, the edit request uses POST with a '_method' parameter as 'PUT' instead of a real PUT request.

Now I want to remove the edit method and send a real PUT request from the frontend. When I used Postman to test this, I found the update method cannot handle a real PUT request.

When I use Postman to send POST + '_method'='PUT' requests, it works fine, but when I send PUT requests, it shows BAD_REQUEST, which is the last line in my code. isSubmitted() returns false.

I know I don't need to use Forms here, but it's been used in the store method. Is it possible to use it to handle a real PUT request? What should I change in my update method?

Comment: How exactly did you see that the form does not handle a `PUT` request?

Comment: Could you try debugging the route? For example you can use the following command to see, if the path + method is correctly translated into the right route name: `bin/console router:match /category/edit --method=PUT`.

Comment: When I use Postman to send POST + '_method'='PUT' requests, it works fine, but when I send PUT requests, it shows BAD_REQUEST, which is the last line in my code. isSubmitted() returns false.

Comment: @dbrumann `sf router:match /categories/{id} --method=POST` doesn't match the update route while PUT does. It seems Symfony treats POST + '_method'='PUT' form submissions as a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing `$entityManager->merge($category);` in the `update()` method. Try adding it above `$entityManager->flush();` and let us know if it works.

Comment: Don't need to merge first here. The object is already managed when using route model binding (It's a laravel term, don't know what's it called in Symfony).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write _method instead of method

`$form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $category, ['_method' => 'PUT']);`

Also you need to persist object, before flushing

Comment: 'method' is a reserved keyword for form options. Check the spec: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick update here using 6.2: Make sure your config `http_method_override` is set to `true` in the framework config.

I was trying to use a `PUT` method in code for a controller method that updates an entity:

```
$form = $formFactory->create($formTypeClassName, $entity, array(
            'action' => Request::METHOD_PUT,
            'method' => $formMethod
        ));
```

The above gets rendered on the front end as a form with a `POST` method, and a hidden input `_method` with `PUT` - as expected.

However: in the `$form->handleRequest($request)` that processes the form data, the method has:

`Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler::handleRequest(FormInterface $form):45`:

```
$method = $form->getConfig()->getMethod();

if ($method !== $request->getMethod()) {
   return;
}
```

`$method` is `PUT`, but the `$request->getMethod()` is `POST` - so instead of 'handling' the request, the handler simply returns and no action is taken.

Once `http_method_override` is set to `true`, both values are `PUT` and action is taken by the handler.